# how to upload attachments as download in sharepoint list items

Tags: sharepoint-2013

By using file upload control, I am posting a word document to list item in list. Now, I should download that file. I already inserted that attachment into list item in attachment column which is predefined but am not able to download that.

The code that i used for uploading is:

```
if (FUploadAttachments.HasFile){
   item.Attachments.Add(FUploadAttachments.PostedFile.FileName, FUploadAttachments.FileBytes);
}
```

My requirement is that should be uploaded as a downloaded link and if I click on that link it should download.

Answer (score 0):

Add the link below to your item path when you show item path to end user;

"/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceURL=/"  +itemPath

I hope, It helps